# Eclipse executable launcher error

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have downloaded Eclipse on my laptop, extracted the necessary files with WinRAR, but when I go to click on the .exe file it gives me an error of "The Eclipse executable launcher was unable to locate its companion shared library". Now from what I have researched, it seems to me that it is a pretty common issue. I've tried things like downloading 7-zip, editing the eclipse.ini file but nothing is working. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download eclipse IDE for developers and extract the whole rar file that you got. Then run eclipse.exe

Answer (score 0):

once download the developer eclipse after extract zip file.open extracted file and double click on  eclipse application symbol.
[image]